# Laravel passport doesn't redirect to callback if client is revoked

Tags: laravel, oauth

I'm using Laravel passport package to use OAuth. It works perfectly fine, but when I set client (In `oauth_clients` table) `revoked` attribute to `1` it doesn't redirect back to my site callback. It just returns JSON response

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Client authentication failed",
    "message": "Client authentication failed"
}
```

but I want to return this JSON response in my callback.. How can I do this?

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: It's normal btw

Comment: Maybe there is a way to change this behavior? I'm thinking about writing API to check if client is revoked, but maybe there is simplier solution, without writing an API?